# make an image sit at the bottom of a section scroll site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a one page scrolling site using bootstrap.  In the header section there is a logo image that is supposed to stay centered at the bottom of the section.  However the image consistently stays at the top

HTML:

```
<header>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">
            <div class="logo container"> <img src="img/logo_black.png" alt="logo"></div>
        </a>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    background-attachment: scroll;
  background-image: url(../img/me.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}

 .logo {
         position: absolute;
         bottom: 0;

     }
```

Comment: You have a text error on your css `<header>`  `position`

Comment: Could you place this into a working fiddle?

Comment: @Paulie_D It even works fine without `position: relative;` at all when you port that code to a fiddle. We can't reproduce the "it appears at the top" error.

Comment: Good point - deleted.

Comment: I've never added anything to a jsfiddle, I'm not sure how to do it.  However, if it is working for you guys can you tell where the problem may be for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Harry Robinsob**, Here is a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjv1om5y/1/)** of your code.
As you had it in the fiddle the logo was stuck to the bottom, it was not centered.

With a little change it is now center.

```
.logo {
    position: absolute;    
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Here is a **[link](https://jsfiddle.net/)** to start your own fiddle.
Sign up to have your own.
Here is a youtube video for a **[Introduction to jsFiddle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrWkRHSK6A8)**.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

header {
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-image: url('http://img1.goodfon.su/original/1920x1080/b/b3/soty-pchela-med-fon-nasekomoe.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
} 
.logo {
    position: absolute;    
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}  
    
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

<header>
    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">
        <div class="logo container"> 
            <img src="https://saasu.com/media/assets/Saasu-Logo-RGB-Black-400px.png" alt="logo">
        </div>
    </a>
</header> 
    
    
    
    

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm curious, Why does left:0, right:0 center the image?

Comment: Hi, great that it's working for you. If we just used `left:0;`it would be hard to the left and same for just the right. But using both seem to pull it evenly between the two and then center it. You can also use it for vertically too.